# show streamming tweets?

Tags: java, jsf-2, twitter4j

Does anyone know how do I show streamming tweet in .jsf page. I want to show user status directly when it comes on my page. I created backing bean named Tweet:

```
@Named(value = "tweet")
@Dependent
public class Tweet {
    private String user;
    private String status;
    private String date;
```

And then set data when it comes in TweetBean:

```
@Named(value = "tweetBean")
@Dependent
public class TweetBean {
...
public void open() {
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
            tweet.setUser("@" + status.getUser().getName());
            tweet.setStatust(status.getText());
            tweet.setDate(String.valueOf(created.format(status.getCreatedAt())));
        }
```

I am having facelet named tweets.xhtml but newly streamed tweets won't show. why? Should I use f:ajax render = "@form" or something else?

```
    <h:body>
    <h:form >
        <div>
            User: #{tweet.user}<br/>
            Status: #{tweet.status} <br/>
            Date: #{tweet.date} <br/>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Anyone?? when value is changed how to update that on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution using PrimeFaces p:poll component like so:

```
<h:form id="form">
<p:dataTable id="statuses" 
             value="#{tweetBean.statusesLinkedList}" 
             var="st" 
             sortMode="multiple" 
             rows="5" 
             paginator="true" >
    <p:column headerText="Message:">
        <h:outputText value="#{st.status}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Date:" sortBy="#{st.date}">
        <h:outputText value="#{st.date}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="User:">
        <h:outputText value="#{st.user}"/>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton type="submit" value="Stop" 
                 actionListener="#{tweetBean.close()}" 
                 ajax="false" action="index?facesredirect=true">
</p:commandButton>
<p:poll interval="3" update="statuses" />
```